# How to compile for 32bit on Qt 5.3.0

Tags: windows, qt, compiler-construction, 32bit-64bit

I have a question: how can i compile the program to work for 32bit using Qt creator 5.3.0. My windows is win 7 eterprise 64bit. (Please give full explanation because i`m not that good at operating systems, i only like algorithmics :D ). Thanks alot.

Comment: Choose a 32-bit compiler in the project kit settings.

Comment: umm, can you suggest a good 32bit compiler for visual application? (i bet it will be one version of MS Visual Studio, but which :D). Thank you.

Comment: On Windows you can use Visual Studio or MinGW.  Download Visual Studio from Microsoft, the express version works fine with Qt, or install MinGW using the Qt maintenance tool.  Assuming you have any compiler installed now you should just be able to choose the 32-bit version in the kit settings.